# Button click reloads the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, zeroclipboard

I have strange problem. 
I am implementing zero clipboard in asp.net.

First I created a page without site master and implemented the zero clipboard and it worked perfectly.

Here is the code.

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Locker.test" %>

        <!DOCTYPE html>

        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head runat="server">
            <title></title>

        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />      
            </form>

                     <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
                     <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.zclip.js"></script>
                     <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
                      <script>
                          $(document).ready(function () {
                              $('#<%=Button1.ClientID%>').zclip({
                                  path: 'ZeroClipboard.swf',
                                  copy: function () { return $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').val(); }
                              });
                          });
                      </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Now when I implement this same code on the page that use Master page, it doesn't work. It trigger I reckon post back so that javascript doesn't get executed.

I checked if autopost back it true but it is set to false.

I am not sure what causing this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code of the page which use Master page.

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="searchResult.aspx.cs" Inherits="Locker.searchResult" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
        <style type="text/css">
            .auto-style1 {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                font-size: large;
            }
            .auto-style2 {
                color: #000000;
            }
            .auto-style3 {
                color: #000000;
                font-size: large;
            }
        </style>
    </asp:Content>

    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

            &nbsp;<p>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong> <span class="auto-style3">Information</span><span class="auto-style1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
             <div style="width:70%; margin: auto auto; text-align:left;">
              <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: large" Text="Details for :" CssClass="auto-style2"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: large; color: #0000FF"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: large" Text="Password :" CssClass="auto-style2"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid"  Enabled="False" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Width="213px"></asp:TextBox>

                  &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                  <input type="text" id="test_description" value="hi" />

                 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.zclip.js"></script>
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
                  <script>
                      $(document).ready(function () {
                          $('#<%=Button3.ClientID%>').zclip({
                              path: 'ZeroClipboard.swf',
                              copy: function () { return $('#<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').val(); }
                          });
                      });
                  </script>
                <br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: large" Text="Description :" CssClass="auto-style2"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Enabled="False" Font-Size="Medium" Height="48px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="213px"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: small" Text="Last Editor was " CssClass="auto-style2"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: small" CssClass="auto-style2"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Edit" Width="97px" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Update" Visible="False" Width="97px" />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: large; color: #0000FF" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </asp:Panel>

             </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: are you getting any error in browser error console

Comment: There is no error in the page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent postback, you may set `UseSubmitBehavior` to `false` on your Button

```
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>
```

See [UseSubmitBehavior description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)